# GNUPlot - Contour Plot Without Isolines?

Tags: gnuplot

I want to know how to do a contour plot of a 3D-dataset, but without the isolines. The closest to what I'm looking for that I've seen are [heat maps](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/heatmaps.html), but that requires your data to be in the form of a matrix (i.e. purely 2D). I've included a picture below, in which you can see the isolines near the center. (By the way, I know contour plots are visual aids and are usually better to keep)

I am producing this plot by taking it from a dataset with columns of the form `X - Y - Z`, and using these commands

```
set pm3d
unset surface
set view map
set contour
set key outside
set dgrid3d 150,150
plot "data.txt" w pm3d
```

[image]

Comment: Please give some more information: what is your data format, which commands did you use to produce the above plot?

Comment: @Joce Thanks, my bad. I edited the question.

Comment: an extract from datafile would also help... cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a point of terminology: a contour plot *is* a plot showing isolines (also called isocontours) of a scalar function of two variables. So you're asking how *not to make* a contour plot, but rather a colour map (or heat map). Then there's the issue of how your data is presented and gridded. You are right that the `matrix` format of gnuplot is only appropriate for data on a regular grid.

If your datafile defines polygon corners in x,y,z coordinates, I would:

```
set view map
set pm3d interpolate 10,10 corners2color mean
splot "res.gdat" notitle with pm3d
```